# How to disable eslint to some folders in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, eslint

I want to disable eslint to some folders when execute `npm run build` in NextJs

I dont want to configure like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    dirs: ['pages', 'utils'], // Only run ESLint on the 'pages' and 'utils' directories during production builds (next build)
  },
}
```

because is complicate to add all my valid folders, but is more easy `if I could pass some folders to be ignored`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ignore specific files or directories, add them to `ignorePatterns` in your eslint config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  ignorePatterns: [
    "jest.config.js",
    "lib",
    "src/some-file.ts",
  ],
  ...
}
```

If you want it to only happen during the build phase, set up a second config file with the `ignorePatterns` and use the appropriate config for what you're doing (dev, build, whatever) with the `-c` or `--config` [CLI option](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-configuration-files).

Comment: How Can I run that config file in Next js build phase?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an .eslintignore file at the root of your project

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code

Answer (score 1):

To disable eslint in some folders in NextJs, you need to edit **next.config.js**, here is the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#linting-custom-directories-and-files

```js
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
   ignoreDuringBuilds: ['/src/core']
  },
}
```

If you want to ignore some folder or files in build phase you need to edit **tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/core/vite.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Upvoting bc this is helpful but note that `ignoreDuringBuilds` only supports a `boolean` in the [latest version of next](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/eslint). Also what does `tsconfig.json` have to do with ESLint?

Answer (score 0):

[Ignoring ESLint](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint)
When ESLint is detected in your project, Next.js fails your production build (next build) when errors are present.

If you'd like Next.js to produce production code even when your application has ESLint errors, you can disable the built-in linting step completely. This is not recommended unless you already have ESLint configured to run in a separate part of your workflow (for example, in CI or a pre-commit hook).

Open next.config.js and enable the ignoreDuringBuilds option in the eslint config:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: I dont want to disable eslint in build, I want eslint ignore some folder in build