# Run eslint in specific folders

Tags: javascript, eslint

**Is there a way to run eslint checks in folders that i specifically want, instead of doing it for whole project?**

The problem is next. Current project has a lot of eslint errors, and i would like to split the work with fixing those errors between team members.

My idea it is that every FE team member would run eslint in some agreed folders and will fix errors specifically there...

Is that possible? Cause i couldn't really find how to do that based on eslint official docs.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73586472/how-to-disable-eslint-to-some-folders-in-nextjs) can help.

Comment: You should watch out for doing stuff like this - it would most likely mean that each team would have different configs which means you would have source control issues.  Probably a better way to do it would be to use eslint-disable on all your files and then get your team members to work through specific folders by removing the eslint disable on the files in their folder

Comment: Thanks @Pete, might try that option as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just run `npx eslint ./path/to/the/folder`. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface#run-the-cli:

```
npx eslint [options] [file|dir|glob]*
```